# Get source value in catchError - RxJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs

I need to get the source value that started the execution of my Observable.
For example:

```js
this.queue = new Subject<Task>();
this.queue.pipe(
    mergeMap(/* ... */),
    mergeMap(/* ... */),
    catchError(<get error and source here>)
);

function addToQueue(source: Task): void {
   this.queue.next(source);
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: you will need to catch the error inside of `mergeMap` and instead throw a custom error object with the `source` attached.

Comment: Yeah, I was just doing that right now. I had a bunch of mergeMap which a converted to a single mergeMap, then I handled any error inside that and returned an object containing the error and my task. I'll test it.